# solr multivalued filed and term frequency strange behavior

Tags: solr, full-text-search

omitTermFreqAndPositions="true"on solr multivalued filed

It is strange for me I've disabled term frequncy reindex and solr still
calcualte tf equal to number of word matched to query..
Why does it happens? Why this works for single valued field but not for multivalued field?
Is it differently stored than concatenation in lucene index?

Comment: omitTermFreqAndPositions does work fine with Mulltivalued fields. Did you restart and reindex the data after the changes ?

Comment: Yes seems reindexing/restarting is not enough I should remove old index also.